# Is it valid to check body background in js or is there a better way to perform the same?

Tags: javascript, css

`bg()` is a function that is triggered on click. Here is `bg()`:

```js
function bg() {
  console.log(document.querySelector('body').style.background);
  if (document.querySelector('body').style.background == "#3e4756") {
    document.querySelector('body').style.background = "#ffffff";
  }
  if (document.querySelector('body').style.background == "#ffffff") {
    document.querySelector('body').style.background = "#0000ff";
  }
  if (document.querySelector('body').style.background == "#0000ff") {
    document.querySelector('body').style.background = "#3e4756";
  }
}
```

So when the button is clicked, I want to keep shuffling between the background colors conditionally.

Comment: I wouldn't say that your approach is invalid. But a pragmatic way would be to define classes for each background: e.g. `.background-white { background-color: #ffffff }`, ... and then check if the class is contained within the class list: `document.body.classList.contains('background-white')`. You can then just switch the background style class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended to not use inline styles, but instead use a class.

Here is a cool solution using [`element.classList.replace(oldClass, newClass)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

When it succeed to replace the old class with the new, it returns true, and when, we know it swapped so we simply return/exit the function.

Stack snippet

```js
document.addEventListener('click', bg);

function bg() {
  var the_body = document.querySelector('body');
  if (the_body.classList.replace("first", "second")) return;
  if (the_body.classList.replace("second", "third")) return;
  if (the_body.classList.replace("third", "first")) return;
}
```

```css
.first {
  background: #3e4756;
}
.second {
  background: #fff;
}
.third {
  background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<body class="first">
  <button type="button">Toggle color</button>
</body>
```

---

Another option would be to store the classes in an attribute, and do something like this

Stack snippet

```js
document.addEventListener('click', bg);

function bg() {
  var the_body = document.querySelector('body');
  var classes = the_body.dataset.swapclasses.split(',');           //get the class array
  var next = classes.shift();                                      //remove/get the first
  the_body.classList.replace(classes[classes.length-1], next);     //swap with the array's last
  classes.push(next);                                              //push it back at the end
  the_body.dataset.swapclasses = classes.join(",");                //save it
}
```

```css
.first {
  background: #3e4756;
}
.second {
  background: #fff;
}
.third {
  background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<body data-swapclasses="second,third,first" class="first">
  <button type="button">Toggle color</button>
</body>
```

---

And of course, if you need to use inline styles, you can use the same trick with those.

Stack snippet

```js
document.addEventListener('click', bg);

function bg() {
  var the_body = document.querySelector('body');
  var classes = the_body.dataset.swapcolor.split(',');           //get the color array
  var next = classes.shift();                                      //remove/get the first
  the_body.style.backgroundColor = next;                           //set new color
  classes.push(next);                                              //push it back at the end
  the_body.dataset.swapcolor = classes.join(",");                //save it
}
```

```html
<body data-swapcolor="#fff,#00f,#3e4756" style="background: #3e4756;">
  <button type="button">Toggle color</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

`.style.background` will return an empty string unless the background style was set inline in the HTML (inside a `style` attribute on the element.)

`getComputedStyle()` is generally a better way to read CSS values -- but note that you're looking for `backgroundColor`, not `background` (which includes backgroundImage, backgroundRepeat, etc); and that browsers are not necessarily consistent about how they represent colors:

```js
let theBody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
let bgColor = window.getComputedStyle(theBody).backgroundColor;

console.log(bgColor);
```

```css
body {background-color: #FFC}
```

To find the string representation the current browser will use for a given color, you'll need to create a new temporary element with that color and then read its color value from the browser as above; then you'll have a string you can safely compare to the value read from the element you actually care about.   `<body>` tags with no background color set are another wrinkle; they return transparent black `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` instead of white (at least on FF, Safari and Chrome on macOS; not sure if that's the same in IE or Edge).   Everything is more complicated than it needs to be, this is why we drink, etc.

For your particular case it would probably be much simpler to skip all that, base your colors on specific class names, and have your function cycle through each classname on the body element.

Answer (score 2):

`getComputedStyle` is important if the background could be set via either css style, or via the style attribute on the element tag. However, if you don't care what the background was via the CSS and you only want to control the background via the style property (like the code you have written) then you could ignore using the `getComputedStyle` function. Besides, when you set the background via the `style` attribute, it will overwrite any background value set by CSS anyway.

Here's a working example that cycles through background colors. I used a global variable `bgColors` for the background colors, and a starting index `bgIndex`. Each time, you click on the button, the `toggleBg()` function is called. The first time it's called, the `body` background is updated to the value at `bgColors[0]` which is `#0000ff`.

The next line, `bgIndex` is updated. It checks to see if the value is greater than the length of the array, if it is, then it sets `bgIndex` to `0`, if it isn't then it increments it by `1`.

So the next time the function is called, `bgIndex` is `1`, so the background gets set to `bgColors[1]` which is `#3e4756`.

```js
const bgColors = ["#0000ff", "#3e4756", "#ffffff"]
let bgIndex = 0;
function toggleBg(){
  const body = document.querySelector("body");
  body.style.background = bgColors[bgIndex];
  bgIndex = bgIndex >= bgColors.length - 1 ? 0 : bgIndex + 1;
}

document.querySelector("#change-bg").addEventListener("click", toggleBg)
```

```html
<button id="change-bg">Toggle Background</button>
```